# Is an iOS 7 targeted application compatible with ios 9?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9

I have an iOS application compiled with xcode 6.4 (base sdk: 8.4, deployment target: 7.0).

As far as I have read, the application should be 100% compatible with devices running iOS 9, am I right?

If yes, why in the past I've read many App store reviews (for other apps) where people complain about apps not working anymore after upgrading iOS?

I've tested the app with an iPad 2 with ios 9 public beta, the app works but crashes quite often; I guess this could be due to the beta version, though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's compatible, as long as you are not using any deprecated APIs (follow iOS9 release notes) - this might also be the reason people complain the app stops working after an iOS upgrade - the use of deprecated APIs by your application

Comment: Thanks, I see the list of changes is very long:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS90APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016222

is there any way to easily check if I am using deprecated APIs or cancelled methods without installing xcode 7?

Comment: @Eugenio unfortunately no I think

Comment: so the only way is by installing xcode 7, compile with io9 as target and if it compiles, I am sure it will work right?

Comment: iOS 9 deprecates some APIs in NSURLConnection.It's not going away because there is so much code written already using it. They recommended all new code written be with NSURLSession. All new networking features and optimization will be applied to NSURLSession henceforth. The Address Book and Address Book UI frameworks are also deprecated.  But finally you have to test you app on iOS9 before submitting to App Store via TestFlight  BetaTesting.

Comment: Deprecated APIs aren't a problem.  Removed APIs can be, but Apple is typically very cautious about removing APIs, ensuring that in the worst case, some minor, optional feature will just stop working (e.g. returning an empty array for a contact list) rather than failing in a more serious way.

Comment: When an app stops working, it is usually either because an app made an assumption about how something worked that turned out to not be guaranteed or because the app was using an API in an unexpected way and Apple never tested that edge case.  Either way, the only way to definitively determine whether an app will work on a future version of the OS is to install that OS and test the app on it.  Anything else is little better than throwing darts at post-its stuck on the wall.